# Django 1.6: Can't display a picture from a model in template.

Tags: python, django, image, templates

I'm trying to display picture from the model, but it doesn't show anything. I uploaded the image using the admin panel and I can see the picture in the uploads folder. But when I try to display it in the templates, it doesn't show anything. I don't have anything is the settings file related to it such as media root, media url, because I'm not sure what to put for them

Here is the template where I'm trying to show it

```
 <img src="{% url 'getDocProfilePicture' doctor.id %}">
```

Here is the models.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    seekers = models.ManyToManyField(DoctorSeeker, through='Review')
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    education1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    education2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
    gender_choices = ( ('M', 'Male'), ('F','Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices = gender_choices, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True)
    statement = models.TextField(null=True)
    affiliation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
```

here is views.py

```
def getDocProfilePicture(request, id):
    d = Doctor.objects.get(id=doctor_id)
    return HttpResponse(d.profile_pic.read())
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^getDocProfileicture/ (?P<id>\d+)/$', views.getDocProfilePicture, name='getDocProfilePicture'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `url` template tag here and have a special separate view.

Just get the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) from the `ImageField`:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ doctor.profile_pic.url }} ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need such complex logic for display image.

```
{{ doctor.profile_pic.url }}
```

Comment: If I put {{ doctor.profile_pic.url }} it shows me this uploads/_20140601_233911.JPG

Comment: you need put it in image tag. Like this <img src="{{doctor.profile_pic.url}}">. I just show how to get image url in template.

Comment: It means that you haven't properly tuned serving media files. Now you have right image url. But it doesn't work because your application doesn't give back media files. Hope this would be useful to you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: @HarisAghadi check out my answer (you probably need to prepend `MEDIA_URL`).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I had the same problem and this solved in my case:

## settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR  = os.path.dirname(__file__)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

## urls.py

Then, my urls.py was missing this line of code to discover the /media/ folder and show the content:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}, name="media_url"),
) + urlpatterns
```

Hope it can help someone.